# Unable to build App bundle in Flutter due to Share Plus package?

Tags: android, flutter, share-plus

**I tried to to build app bundle in Flutter and got the following error message. when I run compile the app in debug mode it is working fine. any help is appreciated.**

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':share_plus:generateReleaseRFile'.
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':share_plus:releaseRuntimeClasspath'.
Could not load module metadata from C:\Users\Mohamed Ramees.gradle\caches\modules-2\metadata-2.97\descriptors\androidx.collection\collection\1.0.0\11cd36a7dcab7d14d0c14c5e6c7582e
3\descriptor.bin

Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 17s
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'... 79.6s
Gradle task bundleRelease failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

```
*this is deprecated for some versions . better use below package , works fine .*
```

https://pub.dev/packages/share_extend